# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object laravel

Tags: laravel

can someone to help me ? i have an error Trying to get property 'id' of non-object laravel while try to show my edit form

this is my controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $produk = produk::where('id',$id)->first();
    return view('produk.edit',compact('produk'));
}


public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    produk::where('id',$id)
        ->update([
            'nama' => $request->nama,
            'id_kategori' => $request->kategori,
            'qty' => $request->qty,
            'harga_beli' => $request->beli,
            'harga_jual' => $request->jual,
        ]);
   return redirect()->route('produk.index');
}
```

this is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class produk extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id','created_at','updated_at'];

    public function kategoris()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\kategori', 'id', 'id_kategori');
    }
}
```

and this is my view

```
<select class="form-control" name="kategori">
    <option value="Pilih Kategori"></option>
    @foreach ($produk as $k)
        <option value="{{ $k->id }}" @if($produk->id_kategori == $k->id) selected @endif>{{$k->nama}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: try to display and die your $id on the edit method. seems that the id is null.

Answer (score 4):

Its because of this

```
$produk = produk::where('id',$id)->first();
```

this returns an object not an array of object. thats why your getting an error  on your view. Instead use:

```
$produk = produk::where('id',$id)->get();
```

to return an array of  object.

Comment: im already follow your answer..
but i still get error Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @IKetutWidhiAdnyana Please post your full error here. To help you better

Comment: @IKetutWidhiAdnyana are you sure you have and id field on your database?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to foreach trough product properties, but looks like you need to foreach trough collection of categories.

Add categories to view in controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $produk = produk::find($id);
    $kategoris = kategori::all();
    return view('produk.edit',compact('produk', 'kategoris'));
}
```

Iterate trough $kategoris (not $produk) in View:

```
<select class="form-control" name="id_kategori">
    <option value="Pilih Kategori"></option>
    @foreach ($kategoris as $kategori)
        <option value="{{ $kategori->id }}" @if($produk->id_kategori == $kategori->id) selected @endif>{{$kategori->nama}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Also, if foreign key is `id_kategori`, it is better to use `name=id_kategori` istead of `name=kategori`

You don't need relation here, because you compare categories ids with id_kategori attribute. But you should replace hasOne to belongsTo in this case.

```
public function kategoris()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\kategori', 'id_kategori');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to obtain the value of the arrangement is 
`$k["id"]` and not `$k->id`

I tried to obtain a field incorrectly with the array, I received the following array

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Ivania", "code": 387}, {"id": 2, "name": "Robert", "code": 389}]
```

Check the array with a foreach

```
$users = $request->input('users');

foreach($users as $key => $user)
    $person = new Person();
    //incorrect form
    //$person->id = $user->id
    //the correct form
    $person->id = $user["id"];
    $person->name = $user["name"];
    $person->code = $user["code"];

    $person-> save ();
}
```